# Problem multiples counter number same page

Tags: javascript, html

i have a problem with my counter number. I need to have several on the same page but if one uploads the other no longer, can you help me?

```js
var str = "@idinstagram";
var n = str.length;
var lungh = n + 750;


function animateValue(obj, start, end, duration) {
  let startTimestamp = null;
  const step = (timestamp) => {
    if (!startTimestamp) startTimestamp = timestamp;
    const progress = Math.min((timestamp - startTimestamp) / duration, 1);
    obj.innerHTML = Math.floor(progress * (end - start) + start);
    if (progress < 1) {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
    }
  };
  window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
}

const obj = document.getElementById('primo');
animateValue(obj, 0, lungh, 2000);
```

```html
<h3 class="heading-14"  id="primo" style="font-size:38px; color:#001a49"  ></h3>
```

Comment: You're lookup logic is based on an id.  If you are going to repeat this for multiple element, you need to switch to using another selector, that allows for repetition

Comment: @Taplar , thanks for the reply, could you tell me how could i do? should i use querySelector? I am new to js so I don't understand some concepts

Comment: id selector returns only first matched element and each element must have unique id on the page...use class selector

Comment: Can you edit your runnable snippet so that it works as is for a single element?

Comment: Guess we know know why it did not work in your last question....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the class as the selector then u can create array from HTML collection and start your method for each

```js
var str = "@idinstagram";
var n = str.length;
var lungh = n + 750;


function animateValue(obj, start, end, duration) {
  let startTimestamp = null;
  const step = (timestamp) => {
    if (!startTimestamp) startTimestamp = timestamp;
    const progress = Math.min((timestamp - startTimestamp) / duration, 1);
    obj.innerHTML = Math.floor(progress * (end - start) + start);
    if (progress < 1) {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
    }
  };
  window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
}

var counters = document.getElementsByClassName('primo');
Array.from(counters).forEach(el => animateValue(el, 0, lungh, 2000));
```

```html
<h3 class="heading-14 primo" style="font-size:38px; color:#001a49" ></h3>
<h3 class="heading-14 primo" style="font-size:38px; color:#001a49" ></h3>
<h3 class="heading-14 primo" style="font-size:38px; color:#001a49" ></h3>
<h3 class="heading-14 primo" style="font-size:38px; color:#001a49" ></h3>
```

Comment: Best answer! Working for me, Thank you!